# sudo is not installing Cordova to root folder on Mac

Tags: macos, cordova, terminal, sudo

Given the Covid situation I'm having to work with students remotely and they are all on different machines.  Specifically I'm attempting to help a student to remotely configure her Mac Book to run Cordova but when she uses node to install it's adding it to her user folder and not to the root user folder.

Overview:

- I can confirm she has 'allow user to administer this computer' toggled on for her account and there are now other users other than guest, so I would think she should have full admin rights.
- She is using **sudo** to enter the command and it's asking for her password to confirm
- She's installing globally using the -g switch

However after installation Cordova is showing in '/User/[name]/.npm/bin/cordova' instead of '/usr/local/bin/cordova' so subsequently the **cordova** command is not recognized.

I use Windows so I'm not as familiar with the MacOS/Terminal but I would think if I can't fix this I can just add her personal user folder to the environment variables but I'm not sure if that opens a new kettle of fish with regards to permissions.

So with that in mind, I'd rather not go down that road if there's a quick solution that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Use nvm to install node so she doesn't need sudo

Comment: Node installs fine so do I'm not clear on why nvm would make a difference.  to be clear it's when she uses npm to install Cordova that it goes to the user folder instead of the root folder.  Are you suggesting that if I use nvm to install an older version of node it would fix this?  Can you clarify for me, thanks.

Comment: I mean node has permissions problems on Mac and using nvm you don't face those problems, but you should never use sudo to install anything

Comment: I get what you mean now.  It turned out the student had two versions installed which was  underlying issue so your suggestion for NVM makes a lot more sense now.  In the end I had her remove everything and re-install and it worked fine.  I suppose if she had to have multiple versions I'd have her use NVM.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: after some more looking around I found that the prefix for node wasn't set correctly.  I'm still not completely sure why this computer was different but regardless setting the prefix corrected the issue.